# jQuery: use dynamic object based on variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several objects and all of them have some methods that are called the same but do different things.

> When I click a button, I want to call the `init()` method, but the
>   object is different based on what button I clicked.

**Here is a snippet**

```
$btn.on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var $trigger = $(this);
    var objectName = $trigger.data('object');

    /*
    if objectName is 'user', I want to call user.init(), 
    if it's 'product' I want to call product.init() and so on...
    right now i get an error if I call like his
     */
    objectName.init($trigger);

});
```

Is it possible to dynamically call an object like this ? I know it is for its properties and methods, but I din't find anything about this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: `var objectName = JSON.parse($trigger.data('object'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to do mapping

```
var entities = {
    user: user,
    entity: entity
}

var objectName = $trigger.data('object');

entities[objectName].init($trigger);
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case your objects (or functions) defined in the global scope, you can access them using the `window` object:

```js
var funcT = function() {
  console.log('funcT was called');
}

var objT = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2
}
function a() {
  var funcName = 'funcT'
  window[funcName]();
  
  var objName = 'objT'
  console.log(window[objName]);
}

a()
```

Answer (score 1):

With `window[variable]` you can access variables based on another variable.

So all that you need to do is to replace `objectName.init($tr‌​igger);` with: `window[objectName].‌​init();`

Comment: They are not global, so I'll stick with Maxx's response. But thank you anyway